# How can I give a truth-value assignment for variables in order for an expression to be false?

Tags: python, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

Given a set of Boolean conditions A, B, C and D.
a. Give a truth-value assignment for A, B, C and D that can make the expression �̅∨
� ∨ �̅∨ � to be evaluated as false.

I cannot understand what means "to give a truth- value assignment.

I tried in Python this code:

```
if a != a or b or c != c or d:
       print("True")
   else:
      print ("False")
Output
 False
```

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-x-or-y-or-z-always-evaluate-to-true-how-can-i-compare-a-to-al) help at all?

Answer (score 0):

`a!=a` is always false because a statement cant be `True` and `False` at the same time. Use `(not a)` instead.

Your example should look like this:

```
if not a or b or not c or d:
       print("True")
   else:
      print ("False")
```

Comment: What is the difference between a != a and not a?

Comment: `a!=a` checks if `a` is not equal to `a`. But For example if `a` is `True` `a!=a` would evaluate to `True!=True` (`True` is not equal to `True`) which is `False` and if `a` is `False` `a!=a` would evaluate to `False!=False` (`False` is not equal to `False`) which is `False`. So `a!=a` is always `False`. You want to invert `a` which you can do with `not`. If `a` is `True` `not a` is `False` and vice versa. I hope that helped. @ΑθανάσιοςΣουλιώτης

Comment: Thanks  alot! Can I also do it like that in order to evaluate it as False?  a = 3
b = 0
c= 9
d= 0

print(bool(not a or b or not c or d))       Output = False

Comment: @ΑθανάσιοςΣουλιώτης Yes. Python evaluates Integer as follows: `0` is `False` and every other number is `True`.